# jQuery Form Plugin + Uploadify

Tags: jquery, forms, plugins, uploadify

I am using the jQuery Form Plugin to process my forms, and a json file is being returned.

The problem I am having is that when using Uploadify, instead of the jQuery Form Plugin calling the success function, the browser instead tries to download json file.

This is the case in IE8, Firefox and Chrome.

Here are headers from a form **without** Uploadify:

> Content-Encoding  gzip
>
> Vary  Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
>
> Content-Length    42
>
> Keep-Alive    timeout=5, max=100
>
> Connection    Keep-Alive
>
> Content-Type  application/json Request
>
> Headers
>
> Host  ksl.crosbiedesign.co.nz
>
> User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh;
>
> Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:5.0)
>
> Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
>
> Accept    **application/json,**
>
> text/javascript, */*
>
> Accept-Language   en-gb,en;q=0.5
>
> Accept-Encoding   gzip, deflate
>
> Accept-Charset    ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>
> Connection    keep-alive
>
> Content-Type  application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>
> charset=UTF-8
>
> X-Requested-With  XMLHttpRequest
>
> Referer   http://ksl.crosbiedesign.co.nz/dimensions/security_permissions
>
> Content-Length    3829
>
> Pragma    no-cache Cache-Control  no-cache

Here are the headers from a form **with** Uploadify

> Date  Thu, 07 Jul 2011 05:51:46 GMT
>
> Server    Apache/2.2.18 (Unix)
>
> mod_ssl/2.2.18
>
> OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5
>
> mod_auth_passthrough/2.1
>
> mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
>
> X-Powered-By  PHP/5.2.17
>
> Cache-Control no-cache,
>   must-revalidate Expires   Mon, 26 Jul
>   1997 05:00:00 GMT
>
> Content-Encoding  gzip
>
> Vary  Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
>
> Content-Length    40
>
> Keep-Alive    timeout=5, max=100
>
> Connection    Keep-Alive
>
> Content-Type  application/json Request
>
> Headers
>
> Host  ksl.crosbiedesign.co.nz
>
> User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh;
>
> Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:5.0)
>
> Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
>
> **Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8**
>
> Accept-Language   en-gb,en;q=0.5
>
> Accept-Encoding   gzip, deflate
>
> Accept-Charset    ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>
> Connection    keep-alive
>
> Referer   http://ksl.crosbiedesign.co.nz/ksl/stockists/add

Answer (score 1):

May be you should just change the `Content-Type` of the response which corresponds to the request's `Accept` header?